# Best way to calculate a stock's fair value

Tags: equities, fair-value

I keep hearing "analysts" say that certain company's stock is currently much below the fair value, and I also keep hearing that certain other stocks are severely over-valued. However, I have no idea how these analysts define fair value of a certain stock. Let us assume for now that we are not really looking at macro-economic factors, and we are simply looking at the company's balance sheet. Is there a nice formula to calculate fair value of a company's stock?

Comment: The "fair value" of a stock, can be calculated using some sort of Discounted Cash Flow (DCF) model. You can take a look at the wiki page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cash_flow).

Comment: Terms like "nice" or "best" don't seem very applicable to me, but: a stock analyst might guess what future earnings might be, and their reasonable ratio to stock price. Or likewise they might guess future dividends and derive a price of this guess.

Comment: Shiller CAPE is one measure of FV and is well-documented online. A more interesting question than, "Is there a nice formula to calculate fair value of a company's stock" might be, "do FV estimates have any predictive power for returns".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. DCF analysis: future values of dividends discounted to today's dollars
2. Comparable company analysis: relative value based on peer group ratios: P/E, P/sales, P/active_user, P/EV, P/TAM for SPACs or ventures
3. Terminal value: total value of assets sold minus liabilities paid

For more details, see [Company Valuation Methods](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=274973) by Pablo Fernandez